# Convert Azure Reserved IP Address (Static VIP) to Public IP address

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Does any one know how to convert an Azure Reserved IP Address (Static VIP) to a Public IP address?

I'd like to move an IP from a cloud service (classic) to a load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to move an IP from a cloud service (classic) to a load
>   balancer.

We can't do it, because classic IP address can't used for ARM. They belong to different mode.

Comment: Maybe we can deploy a site-to-site VPN between classic and ARM, and use the azure reserved IP to create a VM work as a proxy and forward network traffic to load balancer IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this powershell command to do exactly that.  Move-AzureReservedIP